# Do Jdbc driver program like ojdbc6_g.jar contains main() method?

Tags: java, jdbc, database-connectivity

Is Jdbc driver programs like ojdbc6_g.jar is an standalone application or it is only a library file which doesn't have main() method in the main class?

Comment: It is a library. It's not inconceivable that there a `main()` method somewhere in it, but if so it isn't for your use.

Comment: odjbc6_g.jar is same as ojdbc6.jar except that it is compiled with "javac -g" and contains tracing code. Check out the FAQ "What are the different JAR files on the 19.3 JDBC driver download page for?" (https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/faq-jdbc.html)

Answer (score 2):

A JDBC driver is a library for use by Java applications. As such, it doesn't **need** a main class. However, that doesn't mean that JDBC drivers never have a main class.

For example:

- the PostgreSQL JDBC driver has a main class which prints a driver version, a notice that it isn't an executable program, and a basic usage instruction.
- the Oracle JDBC driver declares `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` as its main class, and that prints some version information and diagnostic information.

However the fact these drivers have a main class is no indication that a JDBC driver must have a main class: its primary usage is as a library.

Answer (score -1):

Jdbc driver programs like ojdbc6_g.jar are a library which don't have main function.

Comment: Just like any other Java JAR file, a JDBC driver could have a main class, but that is usually for some basic diagnostic or verification, and you wouldn't normally call it. For example the PostgreSQL JDBC driver has one which just prints the version and that it isn't an executable program and a basic usage instruction.